# Windows BLE UWP disconnect

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

How one forces Windows to disconnect from BLE device being used in UWP app? I receive notifications from some characteristics but at some point I want to stop receiving them and make sure I disconnect from the BLE device to save BLE device's battery?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your application is running  as a gatt client and you have the following  instances your are working with in your code:

```cs
GattCharacteristic myGattchar; // The gatt characteristic you are reading or writing on your BLE peripheral 
GattDeviceService myGattServ; // The BLE peripheral' gatt service on which you are connecting from your application  
BluetoothLEDevice myBleDev;  // The BLE peripheral device your are connecting to from your application
```

When you are already connected to your BLE peripheral, if you call the `Dispose()` methods like this :

`myBleDev.Dispose();` and/or `myGattServ.Dispose()`; and/or `myGattchar.Service.Dispose()`

you surely will free resources in your app but will not cleanly close the BLE connection: The application looses access to control resources for the connection. Nevertheless, connection remains established on the lower levels of the stack (On my peripheral device the Bluetooth *connection active* LED remains ON after calling any of `Dispose()` methods).

Forcing disconnection is done by first disabling notifications and indications on the concerned characteristic  (i.e. *myGattchar* in my example above) by writing a 0 (zero) to the *[Client Characteristic Configuration descriptor](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.descriptor.gatt.client_characteristic_configuration.xml)* for that characteristic through call to method `WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync` with parameter *[GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.None](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.genericattributeprofile.gattclientcharacteristicconfigurationdescriptorvalue)* :

```cs
GattCommunicationStatus status = 
await myGattchar.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(
GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.None);
```

Comment: This is what Microsoft's UWP BLE sample shows you should do. It does not work for me.

Comment: What if a client characteristic does not allow writing to it?
Suppose I only read from the DeviceInformation service --> ModelNumberString characteristic, which is not possible to write this setting to. Then I can't use your method?

Answer (score 1):

Just dispose all objects related to the device. That will disconnect the device, unless there are other apps connected to it.

Answer (score 1):

For my UWP app, even though I've used Dispose() methods, I still received notifications. What helped me was setting my device and characteristics to null. Example:

device.Dispose();

device = null;

Not all to certain of how "correct" this programming is, but it's been working fine for me so far.

Answer (score 1):

The UWP Bluetooth BLE sample code from Microsoft (dispose the BLE device) didn't work for me. I had to add code (dispose the service) to disconnect the device.

```
private async Task<bool> ClearBluetoothLEDeviceAsync()
{
    if (subscribedForNotifications)
    {
        // Need to clear the CCCD from the remote device so we stop receiving notifications
        var result = await registeredCharacteristic.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.None);
        if (result != GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            selectedCharacteristic.ValueChanged -= Characteristic_ValueChanged;
            subscribedForNotifications = false;
        }
    }
    selectedService?.Dispose(); //added code
    selectedService = null; //added code
    bluetoothLeDevice?.Dispose();
    bluetoothLeDevice = null;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Glad I found this!  I have been struggling for hours! I also found that Disposing the service, even though only created as a temporary object was required to properly close the device.

Answer (score 0):

Remember you must call `-=` for events you have called `+=` or `Dispose()` will never really garbage collect correctly. It's a little more code, I know. But it's the way it is.

> Not just with bluetooth stuff, I will remind you - with everything. You can't have hard referenced event handlers and get garbage collection to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Doing all the disposing and null references suggested didn't achieve the Windows (Windows Settings) disconnection I was looking for.

But dealing with IOCTL through [DeviceIoControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ioapiset/nf-ioapiset-deviceiocontrol) did the job.

Answer (score 0):

I found that after calling `GattDeviceService.GetCharacteristicsAsync()`, `BluetoothLeDevice.Dispose()` does not work. So I dispose the Service I don't need.

```
GattCharacteristicsResult characteristicsResult = await service.GetCharacteristicsAsync();
if (characteristicsResult.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
{
    foreach (GattCharacteristic characteristic in characteristicsResult.Characteristics)
    {

        if (characteristic.Uuid.Equals(writeGuid))
        {
            write = characteristic;
        }
        if (characteristic.Uuid.Equals(notifyGuid))
        {
            notify = characteristic;
        }
    }

    if (write == null && notify == null)
    {
        service.Dispose();
        Log($"Dispose service: {service.Uuid}");
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Finally, when I want to disconnect the Bluetooth connection

```
write.Service.Dispose();
device.Dispose();
device = null;
```