# How to disconnect a bluetooth device from UWP app?

Tags: c#, uwp, bluetooth

We have an app that connects to Paired/Unpaired Bluetooth Device.

But to disconnect that device from windows OS, what API should we use?

There are methods like UnpairAsync() but that'll remove the device from paired list.

We are looking for an API that disconnects the device but not unpairs.

Comment: There is no such public method and you have to use some tricks. Our Bluetooth Framework can disconnect any Bluetooth (Classic and LE) connected devices without unpairing it.

Comment: UWP does not have an easy to use method for it, but there are way to do this. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39599252/windows-ble-uwp-disconnect) should hopefully answer your question as well.

Comment: @MARJAN, have you checked my answer?

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT, sorry for belated response. Yes, I just checked. Actually the remote device can send connection request too.

Is there any other API (e.g., Win32)? So that, another process of an desktop app can use that and UWP part communicates with that process via IPC?

Comment: @Velorexe, I am looking for Bluetooth disconnection. Not BLE.

Not necessarily it has to be from UWP. From desktop app, if disconnection can be done, it'll do serve the purpose (as we can bridge that with UWP).

Comment: In win32, I only found [BluetoothRemoveDevice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bluetoothapis/nf-bluetoothapis-bluetoothremovedevice).

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT, I found [WPDApi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/portabledeviceconnectapi/nf-portabledeviceconnectapi-iportabledeviceconnector-disconnect)

Comment: Glad to hear that! If this can solve your problem, you can share it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have talked with Bluetooth Team, and there is no explicit API to disconnect a Bluetooth device from UWP app.

Closing all references to it would help if the system is in central role (i.e. initiated the connection). If the system is in peripheral role (remote device initiated) then the disconnect needs to be initiated by the remote device.

Comment: Hi, can you please talk with Bluetooth team about this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1195468/how-to-disconnect-a-bluetooth-(not-le)-device-from